# Caching an Angular App

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

What's the best way to cache things in Angular when you use ui-router? The problem is when switching between views it does all the $http requests again which is a bit pointless. Options I came up with or read about:

1) *Just store everything to $rootScope.*

Pro: Quickly implemented;
Con: Gets messy with too many objects (globals...)

2) *Make a cache service*

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Cache', function($cacheFactory) {
  var cache = $cacheFactory('Cache');
  return cache;
});
```

To me this is the same as $rootScope since with `Cache.put("someObject", obj);` is pretty much the same as `$rootScope.someObject = obj`?

3) *Cache via $http*

`$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);`

Pro: Doesn't use globals.
Con: Needs to be cleared when retrieved object is changed by user. Probably only good for kind of static content.

4) *Make a service for every cached object*

---

Are there other options? I find none of those above really satisfying...

Comment: One service can hold many objects. As for `$rootScope` you don't want to pollute it because it gets copied many levels deep to create scopes. Services are singeltons

Comment: If ui-router works the same as router, anything that gets resolved in the route will be stored.

Comment: @charlietfl So you would suggest to use a service e.g. 'Cache' and then set and get things e.g. Cache.setItemX(...)?

Comment: Sure. Another alternative is use a data store script if you have a lot of simultaneous incoming/outgoing updates.